# identify words within a phrase and code as 0 or 1

Tags: r, text, match

I am working with utterances, statements spoken by children.  From each utterance, if one or more words in the statement match a predefined list of multiple 'core' words (probably 300 words), then I want to input '1' into 'Core' (and if none, then input '0' into 'Core').

Likewise, if there are one or more words in the statement that match a different predefined listed of 'fringe' words (probably 300 fringe words; again which are different than the core words), then I want to input '1' into 'Fringe' (and if none, then input '0' into 'Fringe').

Basically, right now I have only the utterances and from those, I need to identify if any words match one of the core and match any fringe word.  Here is a snippet of my data.

```
  Core Fringe        Utterance
1   NA     NA            small
2   NA     NA            small
3   NA     NA  where's his bed
4   NA     NA  there's his bed
5   NA     NA  there's his bed
6   NA     NA is that a pillow
```

Thanks in advance. I've searched the archives but have had a hard time finding a solution that corresponds to my situation.

The dput() code is:

```
    structure(list(Utterance = c("small", "small", "where's his bed", "there's his bed", "there's his bed", "is that a pillow", "what is that on his head", "hey he has his arm stuck here", "there there's it", "now you're gonna go night_night", "and that's the thing you can turn on", "yeah where's the music+box"), Core = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Fringe = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output for the snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tidyverse option could be:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

coreWords <- c('small', 'bed')
fringeWords <- c('head', 'night')

df %>%
  mutate(Core = + str_detect(Utterance, str_c(coreWords, collapse = '|')),
         Fringe = + str_detect(Utterance, str_c(fringeWords, collapse = '|')))

#                               Utterance Core Fringe
# 1                                 small    1      0
# 2                                 small    1      0
# 3                       where's his bed    1      0
# 4                       there's his bed    1      0
# 5                       there's his bed    1      0
# 6                      is that a pillow    0      0
# 7              what is that on his head    0      1
# 8         hey he has his arm stuck here    0      0
# 9                      there there's it    0      0
# 10      now you're gonna go night_night    0      1
# 11 and that's the thing you can turn on    0      0
# 12           yeah where's the music+box    0      0
```

Comment: As it turns out, I won't have a list of fringe words. Rather, if there are any additional words that are NOT core words, I need to input '1' for fringe. In other words, I will have a list of core words but not a list of fringe words--anything that is NOT core will count as fringe. If there are ONLY core words, fringe will equal '0'. Is it possible to adjust the script for fringe to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way to maybe solve your question (though I'm sure there are more elegant solutions)...

```
df <- structure(list(Utterance = c("small", "small", "where's his bed", "there's his bed", "there's his bed", "is that a pillow", "what is that on his head", "hey he has his arm stuck here", "there there's it", "now you're gonna go night_night", "and that's the thing you can turn on", "yeah where's the music+box"), Core = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Fringe = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))

## Define object with all the core terms:

CorePatterns <- c("his", "music", "turn")

## Define value of `df$Core` as `1` if `df$Utterance` 
## contains one of the patterns in `CorePatterns`, 
## otherwise, define it as `0`:

df$Core <- ifelse(grepl(paste(CorePatterns, collapse = "|"), 
                        df$Utterance), 
                  1, 0)

df

                              Utterance Core Fringe
> 1                                 small    0     NA
> 2                                 small    0     NA
> 3                       where's his bed    1     NA
> 4                       there's his bed    1     NA
> 5                       there's his bed    1     NA
> 6                      is that a pillow    0     NA
> 7              what is that on his head    1     NA
> 8         hey he has his arm stuck here    1     NA
> 9                      there there's it    0     NA
> 10      now you're gonna go night_night    0     NA
> 11 and that's the thing you can turn on    1     NA
> 12           yeah where's the music+box    1     NA
```

You can do the same with the `Fringe` data.